# Primefaces Datatable unable to select row after ajax update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having what I can call a strange behavior.

I have a page with a panel with several drops downs for search purposes and a datatable in it to display the results.
By default when the page is loaded the values get initialized by a PostContruct init().

I can perform my search without any problem including updating the datatable.

Now, the part where it gets hard for me is the following:
I have a list of tickets with Open/Closed state. My search can be performed with either Open/Closed/ALL.

- By default the datatable is loaded with only the open tickets and I can select them and redirect to another page using the selectedRow value.
- When I choose to filter by Closed status and I click the button to search, the datatable gets updated I can select the rows but when I try to open any page I get a null pointer exception in the bean.
- If I choose all, the datatable gets updated, I can select rows but I can only open the pages with the data that was showed in the first page load, so basically only the tickets that are in the open state. Those that are in Closed that I cannot open them

I'm using RequestScoped bean, I would like to have somehints what could be the problem for the selectRow not work with the new added data.

```
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="searchForm">
            <p:panelGrid id="searchPanel" style="width: 1000px" styleClass="ticketsPanel">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel for="lstStatus" value="Status"></p:outputLabel>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="lstStatus" value="#{ticketController.searchStatus}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Open" itemLabel="Open"></f:selectItem>
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Closed" itemLabel="Closed"></f:selectItem>
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="ALL" itemLabel="ALL"></f:selectItem>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="6" style="alignment-adjust: middle">
                            <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{ticketController.search()}" update=":searchForm:lstTicketsTable"></p:commandButton>
                            <p:commandButton value="Create" action="/tickets/createticket.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"></p:commandButton>
                            <p:commandButton value="View" action="#{ticketController.doUpdateTicket()}"></p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </f:facet>
            </p:panelGrid>

<p:dataTable id="lstTicketsTable" selectionMode="single" paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}  {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,50" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                         value="#{ticketController.ticketList}" selection="#{ticketController.selectedTicket}" var="_tl" rowKey="#{_tl.number}">

                <p:column headerText="Ticket NR">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_tl.number}"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Summary">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_tl.summary}"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Contact From">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_tl.contactfrom}"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Researcher">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_tl.researcher.email == null ? '' : _tl.researcher.email}"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="NSN SR">

                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="SR / CR">

                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Release">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_tl.release}"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Status">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_tl.status}"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Age">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_tl.startdate}"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Priority">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_tl.priority}"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

And the backing bean functions doUpdateTicket is the one being called in the **View** button and the **Search** the one that updates the list of the datatable.

```
public void doUpdateTicket() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    try {
        ec.redirect("/SupportSite/faces/tickets/updateticket.xhtml?tnr=" + this.selectedTicket.getNumber().toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TicketController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void search() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    if (this.searchTicketNR != null) {
        Ticket t = tjc.findTicket(Integer.parseInt(this.searchTicketNR));
        if (t != null) {
            try {
               //This works when search by ticket number only
                ec.redirect("/SupportSite/faces/tickets/updateticket.xhtml?tnr=" + t.getNumber().toString()); 
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TicketController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    } else if (this.getSearchStatus() != "ALL") {
        setTicketList(tjc.findTicketByStatus(this.getSearchStatus()));
        this.init();
    } else {
        setTicketList(tjc.findTicketEntities());
        this.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your XHTML and related java code?

Comment: The best scope for Datatable IMO is ViewScope.

Comment: Updateded with code.
@TapasBose as far as I know ViewScope does not work unless your beans always return null. I need to have conditionally rendered buttons, otherwise I would need to maintain 4 different pages. correct me if I'm wrong please :)

Comment: Alexandre, about your comment, the thing that view scoped beans always have to return null or empty string is about action methods calling, and not in getters of course! You can use there conditionally rendered buttons.

Comment: I believed that was for all. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Also I think you can do things much simpler. Why don't you put the link `/SupportSite/faces/tickets/updateticket.xhtml?tnr=` into your datatable, for each ticket? It's much cleaner than doing a redirection into your action listener method. And, having your ticket status field into your datatable why not to put directly a filter into the datatable itself and let primefaces manage that part?

Comment: Not sure if I'm follow correctly the last part, you mean having a view or procedure and I call from the bean these views?
And putting the link in the database wouldn't that be mixing model with view? still learning here :)